# swift ios cant remove old modal viewcontrollers from stack

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

In my app I am making the account page the new root VC when a user logs in.

It looks like this:

Navigation controller -> table view -> **menu(modal segue) -> login screen(modal segue)** -> account page

When transitioning from login to account I am using:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testVc")

let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
```

This makes the account page the new root VC. But the only problem is that once is shows up both the menu and login form is still visible ontop of the screen.

So how do I clear two old VC's shown as modal?

**Update got it to work using:**

```
  @IBAction func loginButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testVc")

        let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in

        navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)

        }

    }
```

But I dont know if this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the reference of those controllers, and then dismissing them.

Try this:

```
let loginScreen = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController

loginScreen.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
    let menuScreen = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController
    menuScreen.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Should I  place my own code inside that block aswell? It gets fired once you press the "login" button

Comment: I am not sure, try it

Comment: It does not work. Not even removing the two modal VC's

Comment: I almost got it working now, please have a look on my updated question. The only problem now is that there is a delay when removing the modal VC's

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling the original navigation stack and modifying it:

```
let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

You are setting the new view controller (#testVc) by replacing the only other view controller, "tableview", in that navigation stack.

The modally presented views are not a part of that particular navigation stack and instead are presented *above* the current navigation stack as *new* stacks (this gives you a pointer to the new Navigation Controller on top in the form of `self.navigationController` to push new views)

You can explicitly dismiss the two modally presented views by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)` on each, most likely by propagating the communication through a delegate response or through the completion handler.

Comment: Right now it works like: Once you press login button you are taken to the account screen. So do you have a example on how to remove the two old modal VC's?

Comment: I updated my code since I almost got it working now, please have a look. The problem now is that there is a delay when removing the modal VC's